# Utilizar o mesmo jFormattedTextField para máscara de CPF e CNPJ

Tags: java, swing, formatação

Gostaria de saber se é possível em um mesmo `JFormattedTextField`, alternar máscara para CPF e CNPJ.

Quando eu uso a máscara do `JFormattedTextField` o valor já fica estático, e se colocar pra o CPF, não caberá o CNPJ e caso coloque no padrão do CNPJ, o CPF vai ficar desconfigurado.

O que venho tentando fazer são 2 checkBoxes, cada um com sua respectiva distinção e quando selecionados, aplicam a máscara correta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém não está limpando, depois que seleciono alguma máscara. O código pra inserir a máscara que estou usando é:

```
if (jCheckBox1.isSelected()) {
    try {
        MaskFormatter format = new MaskFormatter("##.###.###/####-##");
        format.install(jFormattedTextField1);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FormTeste.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Não. É uma mascara por vez em um campo, a não ser que você mesmo crie sua classe de máscara, substituindo a já pronta na API. Como alternativa menos complicada, você pode controlar que máscara aplicar usando outro componente, como um checkbox ou togglebuton pra mudar a mascara pra um ou pra outro.

Comment: A legal.. teria algum exemplo?

Comment: Você já tem as mascaras de CPF e CNPJ e sua tela com o campo de texto prontos? Elaborar uma resposta explicando como fazer essas mascaras e como alterar entre elas vai tornar a resposta complexa. Adicione o que já fez até agora na pergunta, pro problema ficar mais especifico.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você quer alterar em tempo de execução a máscara do campo, só que o `install` aparentemente não funciona, mas de acordo com [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5204761/5524514), você precisa alterar pela chamada do [**`setFormatterFactory()`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html#setFormatterFactory%28javax.swing.JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatterFactory%29), onde for necessário. No seu exemplo, eu sugeriria mudar para `JRadioButton` para não correr risco de conflito das máscaras.

Você cria um grupo, adiciona os radiobuttons nele, dessa forma, somente será possivel selecionar um item por vez, evitando o problema citado no parágrafo anterior.

```
ButtonGroup radioGroup = new ButtonGroup();
radioGroup.add(radioButtonCPF);
radioGroup.add(radioButtonCNPJ);
```

Também é interessante criar as máscaras antes de usá-las, pra que o tratamento da exceção do `ParseException` ocorra uma vez apenas.

```
private MaskFormatter CNPJMask;
private MaskFormatter CPFMask;

//...

try {
    CNPJMask = new MaskFormatter("##.###.###/####-##");
    CPFMask = new MaskFormatter("###.###.###-##");
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Depois, basta adicionar um [**`ItemListener`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemListener.html) em cada `RadioButton`, e dentro do `intemStateChanged`, verificar se ele foi checado:

```
    radioButtonCPF.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                fmtField.setValue(null);
                fmtField.setFormatterFactory(new DefaultFormatterFactory(CPFMask));
            }
        }
    });

    radioButtonCNPJ.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                fmtField.setValue(null);
                fmtField.setFormatterFactory(new DefaultFormatterFactory(CNPJMask));
            }
        }
    });
```

O `fmtField.setValue(null);` precisa ser chamado antes de aplicar a máscara, pois se tiver algum conteúdo no campo, a troca não é realizada. A consequência disso é que, cada vez que a troca é efetuada, o que foi digitado será perdido.

Dá pra melhorar, mas o exposto já está bem simplificado.

---

Segue um exemplo executável da aplicação de troca de mascaras, caso queira ver funcionando antes de alterar seu código:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.text.ParseException;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory;
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;

public class ChoiceMaskTextFormattedFieldTest extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JFormattedTextField fmtField;
    private JRadioButton radioButtonCNPJ;
    private JRadioButton radioButtonCPF;
    private MaskFormatter CNPJMask;
    private MaskFormatter CPFMask;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new ChoiceMaskTextFormattedFieldTest().setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    public ChoiceMaskTextFormattedFieldTest() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(190, 250));
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        fmtField = new JFormattedTextField();
        radioButtonCPF = new JRadioButton();

        radioButtonCNPJ = new JRadioButton();

        radioButtonCPF.setText("CPF");
        radioButtonCNPJ.setText("CNPJ");

        // adiciona os radiobuttons no groupbutton
        // pra que apenas um seja selecionavel
        ButtonGroup radioGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        radioGroup.add(radioButtonCPF);
        radioGroup.add(radioButtonCNPJ);

        // cria as mascaras e já a deixa pronta pra uso
        try {
            CNPJMask = new MaskFormatter("##.###.###/####-##");
            CPFMask = new MaskFormatter("###.###.###-##");
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        // adiciona um listener aos radiobuttons
        radioButtonCPF.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    fmtField.setValue(null);
                    fmtField.setFormatterFactory(new DefaultFormatterFactory(CPFMask));
                }
            }
        });

        radioButtonCNPJ.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    fmtField.setValue(null);
                    fmtField.setFormatterFactory(new DefaultFormatterFactory(CNPJMask));
                }
            }
        });

        contentPane.add(fmtField);
        contentPane.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(30));
        contentPane.add(radioButtonCPF);
        contentPane.add(radioButtonCNPJ);
        contentPane.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(100));
        pack();
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito bom... Vlw pela atenção!